# Magento extra add review button

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento and what i want is the following:

Under the product reviews on the product page i want to add an extra "add review" button. What I did is add the following link on template\review\product\view\list.html

`<a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><span><?php echo $this->__('Write review') ?>`

The link shows up at the bottom of the product reviews so that goes well but when i click the button nothing happened.

Somebody knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
```